# A mandatory AMP HTML tag is missing from this document

Tags: wordpress, amp-html, google-search-console

I am getting this error with Google Webmaster Tools

> A mandatory AMP HTML tag is missing from this document.

for this page and 27 other page in my webstie:

[https://top7.online/افضل-شاحن-متنقل/amp/](https://top7.online/%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B6%D9%84-%D8%B4%D8%A7%D8%AD%D9%86-%D9%85%D8%AA%D9%86%D9%82%D9%84/amp/)

and when i test my page in URL Inspection I got:

> Linked AMP version is invalid

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the mandatory tags `<meta name="viewport" content="...">` and `<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>` on the link provided.

Inclusion of these two tags *should* resolve both of those errors.

Comment: shall i add this code to my amp template:
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1">

Comment: Yes, I believe that should do it.